# Cannot install certbot with Snap method

Tags: debian, certbot, debian-buster

Following the instruction from certbot website.

https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian

I have got an error when i use this command

```sh
> sudo snap install core
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-575285211: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'.
```

My server running with this configuration

```sh
> lsb_release -a                                                                                                                               
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

> uname -mr                                                                                                                                  
4.19.203-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 x86_64
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, it's not working

Comment: I put a solution directly, the kernel don't have a module squashfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem provide a module squashfs it's not include into kernel, to verify this :

```sh
grep squashfs /proc/filesystems
```

If the result is empty, then the module is probably not load.

To verify if the module exist in your kernel you need following this command :

```sh
modprobe squashfs
```

If you have got an error, then your kernel doesn't support 'squashfs' module.